# Import CSV of UTM points to QGIS

Tags: qgis, csv, import, utm

I am having an extremely difficult time importing my CSV file, with UTM points, to QGIS.

I am a very basic QGIS user, and the online information so far hasn't helped me figure out this problem.

I imported my CSV file using: *Source Manager -> Delimited Text -> CSV -> Point Coordinates...*

But I can not get around how to include the zone in all this.

The zone is in a different column. I have the Easting as the "X" and the Northing as the "Y". My Zone is 10U. When I import it, the data points are in a different hemisphere.

Comment: In the geometry definition section, have you tried entering the easting and northing in the x and y fields then choosing the right CRS? Just find the UTM zone 10 projection and try that.

Comment: I agree with @Gabriel C.. 10U is in the northern hemisphere, so you will want to use UTM 10N (EPSG# 26910 for NAD83, and #32610 for WGS84). If you provide some sample datapoints I can put together an example for you.

Comment: Thanks I will try this!

Comment: Wonderful, Thank you! Told you I was green ;) Now it all makes sense.